# Metric of negative holomorphic sectional curvature

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a Kähler manifold which admits a Hermitian metric of negative holomorphic sectional curvature. Does $X$ admit a Kähler metric with negative holomorphic sectional curvature?

This question is motivated by an old paper of Klembeck's (Geodesic convexity and plurisubharmonicity). In this paper, he shows that the existence of a Hermitian metric on an open Hermitian manifold $X$ with negative Riemannian sectional curvature does not guarantee $X$ is Stein. This issue is circumvented if the metric is Kähler.

Comment: This problem is open when $X$ is compact: if $X$ did admit a Kahler metric with negative HSC then it would have ample canonical bundle (by https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.05802 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01145), and this is not known in general, see conjecture 1.1 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.07165.pdf and also Theorem 1.8 for a partial result

Comment: @YangMills Thankyou for your comment. I was aware of the results of Wu and Yau, but I did not see the arxiv.org/pdf/1610.07165 reference, which I appreciate you pointing out. I'd be interested to see what happens in the following setting: Take $X$ compact Kähler, and let $Y$ be some Zariski dense open subset of $X$. Assume that on $Y$ there is a Hermitian metric of negative holomorphic sectional curvature. Does there exist a Kähler metric on $Y$ of negative holomorphic sectional curvature?